# Why are images visible in Firefox but not in Chrome?

Tags: html, css

These two images are visible in Firefox but not in Chrome.

```
 <img src="../images/tw.png" alt="" class="social-media" />
 <img src="../images/fb.png" alt="" class="social-media" />
```

In Chrome Dev Tools these tags are added: `style="display: none !important;"`

Any ideas why?

Comment: can you share demo link?

Comment: @IshimdarAhamad sorry I can't

Comment: Remove all your plugins and extensions and try again

Comment: @ChrisLear That's probably it thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be a Chrome plugin adding a rule for that class.
Just quickly try it in Incognito mode? There plugins are disabled.

Comment: That was it thanks! Will accept answer soon